# How to Keep the state of an XML View on orientation change Android

Tags: android, view, orientation, android-relativelayout, orientation-changes

I've got the following issue
I'm implementing an app that provides different types of surveys that has different types of supported questions/answers

- RadioButtons
- Check Boxes
- Text Fields
- Image select
- drag & drop items

what I want is when I change the orientation of the device, I keep the same state

i.e --> the text would still be inside the text field ... keep the user's selections on the Radio Group / Check Boxes... etc

I've already tried to override

onsaveInstance & onRestoreInstance

but the problem is I have different types of views & the answer can be viewed as any of them depending on the question type

so I was thinking of saving the whole XML View & then pass it again to the setContentView()

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` in Activity in android manifest file.

**Example**

```
 <activity
     android:name=".ui.Contact"  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

It is Keep the state of an XML View on orientation change .